# Creating space in between written lines

Tags: python, file-io, io

I'm currently creating a function that reads in data from other functions and writing it out to a text file on my desktop.

```
def outputResults(filename):
"""This function serves to output and write the results from analyzeGenome.py to a text file \
   Input: filename of output file, dictionary of codon frequencies, dictionary of codon counts \
        GC-content, FASTA header, & sequence length

   Output: Text file containing all the above """

outString = "Header = %s" %header
filename.write(outString)

outString2 = "Sequence Length = %.3F MB" % length
filename.write(outString2)
```

When I do this, python prints the lines one after another in the text file. How can I print onto the next line and add a space in between the lines?

Answer (score 5):

You need to append a linebreak.
http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html

`output.write('First line.\n')`

Comment: @Francis The `\n` goes right where you want the linebreak, in the string. Looks to me like it goes right after `%s`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of write, use [writelines](http://docs.python.org/release/2.2.3/lib/bltin-file-objects.html), which prints everything in the sequence out to a file on its own line. Add a blank string to add double spacing

```
  filename.writelines([outString, "", outString2]);
```